# Dedicated graphics card needed for small RDP setup?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, graphics

I want to set up an RDP host (Win Server 2012) for a maximum simultaneous use by **8 clients**. Only "normal" applications will be run (no CAD or games). Do I need a dedicated graphics card or will an integrated chip (AMD A-Series or Intel HD) do?

Comment: I don't know if this makes any difference but I should add that the clients are Sun Thin Clients (fed by an intermediary oracle linux server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brief answer, no you don't need a graphics card.

By default the RDP sessions will never benefit from the graphics card because the RDP protocol driver acts as the graphics device.

> RDP plugs into the Windows graphics system the same way a real
>   display driver does, except that, instead of being a driver for a
>   physical video card, RDP is a virtual display driver. Instead of
>   sending drawing operations to a physical hardware GPU, RDP makes
>   intelligent decisions about how to encode those commands into the RDP
>   wire format. This can range from encoding bitmaps to, in many cases,
>   encoding much smaller display commands such as “Draw line from point 1
>   to point 2” or “Render this text at this location.”

From https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rds/2009/03/03/top-10-rdp-protocol-misconceptions-part-1/

So the bit about the AMD or Intel on-chip graphics is kind of irrelevant.

<s>Microsoft do have a RDP technology called RemoteFX, which (amongst other things) allows you to leverage a physical GPU on the RDSH to accelerate graphics in RDP sessions.  It's pretty much unnecessary for standard office applications.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RemoteFX</s>

Apologies for the prior incorrect, the RemoteFX GPU features only apply to virtual desktops, not normal RDP sessions.

Comment: IIRC RemoteFx also requires a special VM in which the remote desktop works - i.e. it is not "an RDP setup" (which implies terminal services) but a "you have your own VM, dear user, and we use the graphics card" setup. Much more hardware intensive.

Comment: OH yes TomTom, you;re quite correct.  I'm sure there is some way of doing RDP with hardware GFX acceleration though, just can't remember how it works?  Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I was looking into the issue more during the day and your answer now reassured me.